# Copy UIEvent object in touchesBegan Method

Tags: xcode, touchesbegan, uievent

I'm trying to pass the UIEvent object received by touchesBegan method to other objects that have to extract the touches from this event to do things.

The problem is when the first responder receives the event in the first call to touchesBegan and calls the touchesBegan of secondary objects using the object event as parameter, when the secondary object try to extract the UITouches from this events, nothing is returned because the UIEvent is empty.

I've tried to "copy" the event in order to save the original event and use it but without success.

Is there any way to create a clone of an UIEvent object as an independent object?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just pass the touch locations?  That way, there's no extraction necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no any way to create the clone of `UIEvent`. The only thing you can take the reference of `UIEvent`.